# How do I convert a method's local variable or expression to a method parameter using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

How do I convert a method's local variable or expression into a method parameter using Eclipse's built-in refactoring tools?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "Introduce Parameter" option on the Refactor.. submenu when you right-click.

You'll need to select an expression, such as the expression used to initialise the local variable, for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the declaration of your local variable, the places you used that variable will no longer compile. You can then choose "Add parameter" from the quick fix menu (Ctrl-1 I think, don't have Eclipse open now).

Comment: Although it doesn't use the Eclipse refactor feature, this works just as well